# How Can I override property in Inheritance relationship in PROLOG?

Tags: inheritance, prolog, overriding

I want to make a rule that utilizes inheritance.
For example, here is a famous example that is used in many prolog books, describing inheritance.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [unak.is](http://staff.unak.is/not/tony/teaching/ai/lectures/09bSemanticNet/lab18/birdSemanticNet.gif))</sub>

and here is facts for these relationship:

```
%Bird
%animal's childs
isa(bird, animal).
isa(fish, animal).

%bird's childs
isa(ostrich, bird).
isa(penguin, bird).
isa(canary, bird).
isa(robin, bird).

%penguin's childs
isa(opus, penguin).

%canary's childs
isa(tweety, canary).

%animal's property
hasprop(animal, covering, skin).

%bird's property
hasprop(bird, travel, fly).
hasprop(bird, covering, feathers).

%fish's property
hasprop(fish, travel, swim).

%ostrich's property
hasprop(ostrich, travel, walk).

%penguin's property
hasprop(penguin, travel, walk).
hasprop(penguin, color, brown).

%canary's property
hasprop(canary, color, yellow).
hasprop(canary, sound, sing).

%robin's property
hasprop(robin, color, red).
hasprop(robin, sound, sing).

%tweety's property
hasprop(tweety, color, white).

%rules
hasproperty(Object, Property, Value) :- hasprop(Object, Property, Value),!.

hasproperty(Object, Property, Value) :- isa(Object, Parent),
                                        hasproperty(Parent, Property, Value).
```

In this network, when I query a statement like hasproperty(penguin, X, Y), I could only get the one result(and I know this is because of cut operator.). What I want is the result that like this:

```
?- hasproperty(penguin, X, Y).

X = travel,
Y = walk.

X = color,
Y = brown.

X = covering,
Y = feathers.
```

In this result, lower level classes' properties, travel and covering override those of upper level classes. But I do not have any idea dealing with these overridings. If you have any solution regarding this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach would be to check the immediate object property in your second `hasproperty/3` clause:

```
hasproperty(Object, Property, Value) :-
    hasprop(Object, Property, Value).

hasproperty(Object, Property, Value) :-
   isa(Object, Parent),
   hasproperty(Parent, Property, Value),
   \+ hasprop(Object, Property, _).  % Let object property override
```

Comment: Oh, I got it, and it works without any problem. really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to simply represent your hierarchy using Logtalk objects and declaring and defining object predicates for representing the properties. You can run Logtalk using SWI-Prolog as the backend Prolog compiler or any other of the supported Prolog compilers. Given the number of nodes in your hierarchy, I will exemplify only for a few of them:

```
:- object(animal).

    :- public(covering/1).
    covering(skin).  % default covering

    :- public(travel/1).

:- end_object.


:- object(fish, extends(animal)).

    travel(swim).

:- end_object.


:- object(bird, extends(animal)).

    covering(feathers).
    travel(fly).

:- end_object.
```

After defining all necessary objects and predicates, is trivial to ask a specific object for their properties or for their property values. For example:

```
?- bird::current_predicate(Property).
Property = covering/1 ;
Property = travel
true.

?- bird::travel(Travel).
T = fly
true.
```

Inheritance, including overriding, comes for free. The equivalent of the `hasproperty/3` predicate would be something like:

```
?- current_object(Object), Object::current_predicate(Functor/Arity), functor(Property, Functor, Arity), Object::Property.
```

Your hierarchy is now nicely represented, easy to modify, and you can even use Logtalk's diagrams tool to get a PDF with it resembling your picture above.